# Проблема подключения к MySql контейнеру с php-apache контейнера

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, lamp

Запускаю три контейнера(php-apache,mysql,phpmyadmin) через docker:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -v ~/hello-world:/var/www/app -d "romeoz/docker-
apache-php:5.4" 
&&
docker run --name main_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e 
MYSQL_DATABASE=main -p 3306:3306 -d mysql 
&&
docker run --name myadmin -d --link main_mysql:db -p 8080:80 
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

К MySql спокойно могу подключится через DataGrid, phpmyadmin - работает.
В php проверяю подключение кодом:

```
<?php
 try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=main', 'root', 'root');
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from test') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
$dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}?>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: Аналогичная проблема возникала с использованием готовых docker-compose LAMP/LEMP стеков с GitHub.
Как решить проблему?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. // соединение должно быть по протоколу tcp, а не через unix-socket. для того, чтобы вынудить pdo использовать именно tcp, для начала попробуйте явно указать порт в [dsn](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). ну и mysqld, конечно, должен слушать tcp (по умолчанию скорее всего не слушает, а использует unix-socket).

Comment: Вам же прямо движок пишет, что он пытается подключиться к юникс-сокету (файлу), вам нужно подключаться по адресу и порту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл проблему, нужно использовать при подключении не 'localhost' а 'db'.